# Debug tips about wrapping C code with Julia

Tags: c, wrapper, julia

**The C struct:**

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t tid;
    int32_t pos;
    uint32_t bin:16, qual:8, l_qname:8;
    uint32_t flag:16, n_cigar:16;
    int32_t l_qseq;
    int32_t mtid;
    int32_t mpos;
    int32_t isize;
} bam1_core_t;

typedef struct {
    bam1_core_t core;
    int l_data, m_data;
    uint8_t *data;
    uint64_t id;
} bam1_t;
```

**The Julia data type I write:**

```
type BinQualLqname
    bin::UInt16
    qual::UInt8
    l_qname::UInt8
end

type FlagNCigar
    flag::UInt16
    n_cigar::UInt16
end

type Bam1_core_t
    tid::Int32
    pos::Int32
    bin_qual_lqname::BinQualLqname                                                                                 
    flag_ncigar::FlagNCigar                                                                                                 
    l_qseq::Int32
    mtid::Int32
    mpos::Int32
    isize::Int32
end

type Bam1_t
    core::Ptr{Bam1_core_t}
    l_data::Int32
    m_data::Int32
    data::Ptr{Cuchar}                                                                                 
    id::UInt64
end
```

When I used above Datatype `Bam1_t` in julia function:

```
function sam_read1!(samfile,bamheader,b::Ptr{Bam1_t})
    record = ccall((:sam_read1,"libhts"),Cint, (Ptr{Void},Ptr{Void},Ptr{Bam1_t}),samfile,bamheader,b)                                                                                        
end
```

The data in b modified by `sam_read1!` is nonsense. How can I debug this? Is there any tools or tips recommended?

Comment: In the C structures, why use bit-fields instead of actual 8 or 16 bit types? If you're worried about padding just about all compilers have extensions to remove it.

Comment: The C code is written by other people, I am trying writing a Julia wrapper for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sam_read1

```
int sam_read1(tamFile fp, bam_header_t *header, bam1_t *b);
```

where

```
typedef struct { 
    bam1_core_t core; 
    int l_aux, data_len, m_data; 
    uint8_t *data; 
} bam1_t;
```

Seems to be different than your Bam1_t. Would

```
type Bam1_t
    core::Bam1_core_t
    l_aux::Int32
    data_len::Int32
    m_data::Int32
    data::Ptr{Cuchar}
end
```

work?

Comment: The type of `core` in `Bam1_t` should be `Bam_core_t`. You are right. I will try it. Thank you very much.